# Pushed resources get downloaded twice and warnings about crossorigin

Tags: cross-domain, http2, preload, server-push

I try to use http/2 server-push to preload some assets within a Laravel Website.

```
<!-- Preload -->
<link href="/fonts/Logo.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" rel="preload" crossorigin>
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="preload" as="style" type="text/css" crossorigin>
<link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" type="application/javascript" as="script" crossorigin>
<!-- Use -->
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="module" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

I'm using a [Middleware](https://github.com/HepplerDotNet/laravel-HTTP2ServerPush) to set Link-Headers.

However, the script and font get downloaded twice (push and normal request)

They both also produce warnings

**"A preload for 'https://localhost/fonts/Logo.woff' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute."**

**"A preload for 'https://localhost/js/app.js' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute."**

I tried to remove `crossorigin` from all three tags, but this didn't solve the issue. Also tried different combinations like `crossorigin="use-credentials"` or `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone has the same issue.
The Link HTTP-Header has to contain crossorigin for Font/Script, but not for CSS/Image

Comment: Can you post the code that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the very same `preload` attribute to your usage link

So instead of your

```html
<!-- Preload -->
<link href="/fonts/Logo.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" rel="preload" crossorigin>
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="preload" as="style" type="text/css" crossorigin>
<link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" type="application/javascript" as="script" crossorigin>
<!-- Use -->
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="module" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Put

```html
<!-- Preload -->
<link href="/fonts/Logo.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" rel="preload" crossorigin>
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="preload" as="style" type="text/css" crossorigin>
<link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" type="application/javascript" as="script" crossorigin>
<!-- Use -->
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin>
<script type="module" src="/js/app.js" crossorigin></script>
```