# Fetch request for JSON file not hitting link preload

Tags: javascript, html, cors, fetch-api, preload

I have an HTML preload that looks like this:

```html
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/_data/file.json"
  as="fetch"
  crossorigin="use-credentials"
>
```

(I have tried it with every permutation of the `crossorigin` attribute)

and then JS that looks like this:

```js
fetch(dataPath, {
  method: 'get',
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

(I have tried it with every permutation of the mode and credentials options.)

These two lines produce identical request headers:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4005/_data/file.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: [::1]:4005
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4005
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 01 Aug 2023 21:24:04 GMT
If-None-Match: W/"1bdb-189b2fc9372"
Origin: http://localhost:4005
Referer: http://localhost:4005/path
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

And yet I continue to get the error in Chrome and Safari:

> The resource http://localhost:4005/_data/file.json was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

With some crossorigin HTML attribute / fetch CORS options permutations I also get the warning:

> request_json.js:11 A preload for 'http://localhost:4005/_data/file.json' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute.

Why is the preload not being used by the browser? It seems the same thing is happening with HTTPS on production, but there the same JS isn't causing an origin header to be sent as it is locally.

I've looked at many other stack overflow questions that concern the same errors eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680510/pushed-resources-get-downloaded-twice-and-warnings-about-crossorigin), but either the solutions don't help or I don't understand what has to change, eg I don't think I'm sending a "Link HTTP-Header" but I'm not sure how.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `credentials: 'include'`? Is your `_data/file.json` static or dynamic? Does it actually require cookies in the request?

Comment: @Phil No specific reason, I was just trying every combination. If I do `fetch(URL, { method: 'get', mode: 'no-cors'})` and remove the `crossorigin` attribute, or use `crossorigin="anonymous"` I get the same error. File.json is static.

Comment: @Phil The original reason I put it in was because I read somewhere that JS/JSON preloads always have to be CORS, so I was trying to trigger it to handle it with CORS even though it is a same-origin request

Comment: I wasn't asking about the `mode` (which defaults to `'cors'` anyway), I was asking about `credentials`

Comment: @Phil I meant that if I put ie exhaustively `fetch(URL, { method: 'get', mode: 'no-cors'})` with no credentials option specified, the error still occurs. Does that make sense?

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors'` will **never** work for what you're trying to do. Again, I was not asking about `mode` so I'm not sure why you've repeated it

Comment: @Phil Hi, I was just trying to be clear about what line of code I was running. I have tried it with a credentials option set to 'include', and I have tried it with no option set (and with no 'mode' option set.) Is that what you were asking about, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I asked **why** you were trying to use `fetch()` with the `credentials` option when cookies would not be involved at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your JSON file is static, you shouldn't need any *credentials* (aka cookies). This means you can use `crossorigin="anonymous"` in your `<link>` and omit the `credentials` option in `fetch()`

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/_data/file.json" as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

```js
fetch("/_data/file.json")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    // ...
  });
```

The `fetch()` defaults include `method: "GET"` and `mode: "cors"` so there's no reason to explicitly set them.

---

Note that `<link>` tags should ideally be placed in the `<head>` section of your document. At the very least, they should occur **before** anything that attempt to use the preloaded assets.

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for putting this together. This was one of the permutations I tried, but unfortunately it still produces the same error. (I'm using `crossorigin="anonymous"` in the HTML and no options arguments to fetch)

Comment: @ak0000 exactly what error would that be? Make sure you've cleared your browser cache between attempts

Comment: The error is `The resource http://localhost:4005/_data/file.json was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.` Using an empty cache and hard reload. I can try to make a minimal reproduction. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ak0000 Well are you making the `fetch()` request within a few seconds of the page load? If I delay the request by ~10s using `setTimeout()` I can certainly reproduce that error but otherwise, it works fine... I see the request for the JSON file on page load and don't see another when the `fetch()` happens

Comment: The preload `<link>` should be in your document's `<head>` section or at the very least **before** the `<script>` tag

Comment: cool, let me make that change and see if it resolves the issue

Comment: looks like this resolves the issue, although I am surprised because I was using the network tab and the preload was clearly being made before the JS was even finished downloading, so I would have thought that it would go by chronology of network requests, not the chronology of the HTML. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: another note is that I preload an image in the HTML body and that was always working, curious why that would be